# Similar method, different answers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Ryan goes to church 2 days a week and college 3 days a week. On exactly one day he goes to church and college both. He went to college on Friday what is the probability he went to church the next day.

Textbook approach:

> [image: 1. Text book method]

2. My approach :

   *CASE : 1 HE WENT TO CHURCH ON FRIDAY*

Mo Tu Wed Thu Fri(**COLLEGE,CHURCH**) Sat Su

All cases

- There are 6 choices to select the next day to visit church : 6C1 = 6
- For each of the above choices, there are 5 choices to select 2 college dates : 5C2 = 10

Favorable cases

- Church on Saturday
- Select 2 days of college from the rest of 5 days : 5C2 = 10

Probability due to CASE 1 : (10/60)

*CASE : 2 HE DID NOT GO TO CHURCH ON FRIDAY*

Mo Tu Wed Thu Fri(**COLLEGE**) Sat Su

All cases

- 6 days to select 2 college dates : 6C2 = 15
- Select 1 out of those 2 dates for church, select 1 more date out of the left 4 days : 2C1 x 4C1 = 8

Favorable cases

- **Sat** is when he visits church
- Out of the remaining 5 days(**Fri** is not church) select 1 more day for church : 5C1 = 5
- Out of the 2 days of church select 1 day for college : 2C1 = 2
- Out of the remaining 4 days select 2 for college : 4C2 = 6

Probability due to CASE 2 : (60/120)

Total probability : (10/60)+(60/120) = 2/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to inform you where you are doing wrong:
In Case2) In the part of "favorable cases," the last bullet should be 4C1 because now we left with 1 choice of college day (Friday and one between the church days have been selected).

By this we get 40/120 that is 1/3 (fourth term in textbook's answer).
Similarly, In Case1), we got 10/60 that is 1/6 (2nd term in textbook's answer).

Now comes to the real explanation, you are calculating the probability in two different events for that you also have to consider the probability of the events.

Two different events are clear to you. Please read the textbook's explanation
once again keeping in mind the probability of events.

Further doubt maybe that why it is 1/3 because the only information we have is about Friday and that day he went to college for sure that means this is that one day of his total college days when he also goes to church.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you get the same probability as book author for the first case: $\frac{10}{60} = \frac{1}{6}$.

The first problem is the probability in the second case. It is already known that Friday is day for college, so in the last sentence you should select only 1 day (not 2) for college out of the remaining 4 days: $\binom{4}{1} = 4$. Then you get probability in the second case $\frac{40}{120} = \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{6}$.

The second and the main problem is that two cases described in both solutions are neither equiprobable nor summable. The probability in the first case can't be just added to the probability in the second case. An easy argument is that you could potentially get a result greater than 1, that is not a good idea. More rigorous argument is [Bayes' theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BayesTheorem.html).
The probability that Ryan went to church on Friday subject to he went to college on Friday is $\frac{1}{3}$, because one of 3 days he goes to college he also goes to church. For the same reason the probability that Ryan didn't go to church on Friday subject to he went to college on Friday is $\frac{2}{3}$.

A rigorous solution is the following.

$$\mathrm P\{\text{Ryan went to church on Saturday} \mid \text{Ryan went to college on Friday}\} = \mathrm P\{\text{Ryan went to church on Saturday} \mid \text{Ryan went to college and church on Friday}\} \cdot \mathrm P\{\text{Ryan went to church on Friday} \mid \text{Ryan went to college on Friday}\} + \mathrm P\{\text{Ryan went to church on Saturday} \mid \text{Ryan went to church and didn't go to church on Friday}\} \cdot \mathrm P\{\text{Ryan didn't to to church on Friday} \mid \text{Ryan went to college on Friday}\} = 
\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{6} = \frac{5}{18}.$$